# Submit form without rereshing page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have the following code:

```
(function myFunction() {
$('form#uploadform').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.post('UploadServlet', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
        // This is executed when the call to mail.php was succesful.
        // 'data' contains the response from the request
    }).error(function() {
        // This is executed when the call to mail.php failed.
    });
    e.preventDefault();

});

return false; 
});
</script>

   <form action="UploadServlet" method="post" id="uploadform"  
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="picture" size="50" placeholder="Browse Image" />
              <br />
           <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
           </form>
```

I have an upload file functionaility, I want to upload file but want to stay on same page, I tried the above function but it did not work and I get redirected to a different page?

Comment: by doing this it didnt call the servlet, which i want to happen

Answer (score 0):

Your function that runs on `submit` needs to return `false`, so that the normal submission of the form via the browser does not happen.

Comment: Are you sure your function is called on submit (the one doing the $.post)?

Comment: I made the following changes: added the <button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>, but still no change, still redirects to different page.